# Graph checkin Facebook api always returns empty

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get to work the checkin method to get the places of a user, it only returns empty data:

```
{  "data": [  ]}
```

This is my code in javascript:

```
FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.authResponse){
    FB.api('/me', function(me){
        if (me.id) {
            var facebook_userid = me.id;
            alert(facebook_userid);
            FB.api('/'+facebook_userid+'/checkins', function(response) {
                alert(response);
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
            }
}, {scope: 'email,user_status,user_checkins,user_likes,user_location'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. It works fine.

```
  FB.login(function(response){
    if(response.authResponse){
      FB.api('/me?fields=posts.with(location)', function(response){
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  }, 
  {scope: 'email,user_status,user_checkins,user_likes,user_location,read_stream'});
```